Linear Tool movement with ROS2 moveit2 as in Rviz
I am using a real UR10e controlling it with ROS2 Humble on my Ubuntu 22.04. I am able to control the arm through Rviz when I ros2 launch ur_moveit_config ur_moveit.launch.py ur_type:=ur10e launch_rviz:=true and the visual interface works great to move the arm. When I plan a linear path by dragging the tool in either x,y or z direction I am able to execute linear movements and the terminal informs me that:

[move_group-1] [INFO] [1718628074.732908060
[moveit.simple_controller_manager.follow_joint_trajectory_controller_handle]: Controller 'scaled_joint_trajectory_controller' successfully finished

Now I have tried using this somehow to reproduce a linear tool movement from a C++ script but have had no luck and am not really sure how to start. Is this even possible? Any help is appreciated!
PS: If there is another simple way to replicate this linear motion I would also greatly appreciate the pointers. I don't want to run URscript because it seems as though you can only do so by interrupting the external control program running on the UR.

You should try and use the Pilz Cartesian planner.
Add Pilz_planning.yaml and pilz_cartesian_planner.yaml for your move_group.

Thank you for the idea, I have tried but have struggled to load pilz_planning.yaml as well as pilz_cartesian_planner.yaml into my launch file. I  ros2 launch ur_robot_driver ur_control.launch.py ur_type:=ur10e robot_ip:=192.168.1.102 use_tool_communication:=true use_fake_hardware:=false launch_rviz:=false tool_voltage:=24, and then ros2 launch my_controller pilz_launch.py but get an error stating that [INFO] [spawner_ur_manipulator]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' services to be available [ERROR] [spawner_ur_manipulator]: Controller manager not available

I don't have experience with UR at all but I do know that Pilz is not a controller, it is a planner plugin for Moveit you should use a regular controller like follow_joint_trajectory
and check your planning plugins available on Moveit startup.
